# Streaming JSON data saving as Parquet in S3

Tags: json, avro, parquet, amazon-kinesis

I've a Kinesis stream producing JSON and wanted to use Storm to write to S3 in Parquet format. This approach will require conversion from JSON --> Avro --> Parquet during stream processing. Also, I need to deal with schema evolution in this approach and keep updating avro schema and avsc generated java classes.

Another option is directly writing JSON in S3 and use Spark to convert stored files to parquet. Spark can take care of schema evolution in this case.

I would like to get pros and cons of both of the approaches. Also, is there any other better approach that can deal with schema evolution in json-->avro-->parquet conversion pipeline?

Comment: Why JSON -> Avro -> Parquet? Why not just go straight to Parquet?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?